# Disable form submission on pressing enter because i am using Ajax functionality

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I am using ajax functionality. When i am selecting any suggestion using enter key, the form get submitted automatically because the submit button is auto-focused. Is there any way to select ajax suggestion using enter key as well submit the form using enter key. Something like when i input the values of all the fields then only submit button get enabled.

Answer (score 4):

How are you calling your Ajax function? It should be inside the `submit` event handler of the form. And then if you have the event handler return `false` it won't submit normally:

```
<form onsubmit="doAjaxSubmit(); return false;">
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like this would solve the problem, since hitting enter on the auto-complete field would still cause an AJAX submission.

Comment: but i am using one form validator method on the onsubmit call how i'll call this method if there would doAjaxSubmit().

Answer (score 2):

You can detect which key is pressed using the `.keypress()` method. From this you should be able to `return false;` for form submit and do your ajax stuff on the back of it in an `if` statement:

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: i am not using jquery for the ajax functionality, so cant use Jquery.keypress() function.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your form's `onSubmit` return `true` if all the fields have values, or `false` if they don't.